# Pandas renumber unique occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 11, 11, 16, 17, 17, 19]})

>>> data
    ID
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    4
8   11
9   11
10  16
11  17
12  17
13  19
```

How can I simply renumber thet values as a column in a dataframe so that they are sequential, i.e. the output of data is:

```
>>> data
    ID
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    4
10   5
11   6
12   6
13   7
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a dict mapping the `unique` values in your ID column to your new sequential values and then call `map` passing in this dict:

```
In [48]:
d = dict(zip(data['ID'].unique(), np.arange(1, len(data['ID'].unique()) + 1)))
d

Out[48]:
{1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 3, 11: 4, 16: 5, 17: 6, 19: 7}

In [49]:
data['ID'] = data['ID'].map(d)
data

Out[49]:
    ID
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    4
10   5
11   6
12   6
13   7
```

**EDIT**

Actually a better way would be to call [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank) on the column and pass param `dense`:

```
In [56]:

data['ID'] = data['ID'].rank('dense')
data
Out[56]:
    ID
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    4
10   5
11   6
12   6
13   7
```